# THREE.js Keeping track of Models (objects)

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am loading .obj files using THREE.OBJLoader() and pushing each object in myobj[] array after adding it to screen.

```
var myObjs = [];
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
var object = event.content;
object.position.x=xpos;
object.position.y = ypos;
scene.add( object );
teeth.push(object);
});
loader.load( 'obj/myobj1.obj' );
loader.load('obj/myobj2.obj');
loader.load('obj/myobj3.obj');
```

I can check whether an object is clicked or not using the following code:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

event.preventDefault();
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - (   event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );


projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( teeth, true );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

intersects[0].object.position.z=50;
}
```

So far so good. Now what I can't figure out is how to track which of my object in myobjs[] array was click or should I say how can I map intersects[0].object in myobjs array.

Regards,
ZB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object will be exactly the same, i.e. `intersects[0].object` and some `myobjs` array member will both be references to the same instance. If you want to find the index to the `myobjs` array (for example in order to delete it from there), you have several choices:

1. After intersection, loop through `myobjs` and compare `intersects[0].object.id` to `myobj[i].id` (each three.js object has a unique `id` property).
2. You are also free to assign any suitable custom properties to the object in your `load` event handler, so simply add a line `object.myId = myobjs.length;` just before pushing it to `myobjs` and you can index the array later with `intersects[0].object.myId`.